# Spring MVC, form:errors del jsp no muestran los errores de validación

Tags: java, jsp, spring, spring-mvc

Soy nuevo usando el framework Spring y no soy capaz de solucionar el siguiente problema.

Quiero realizar la validación de un formulario mediante una clase implementada a partir de Validator. Aquí compruebo que hay una serie de errores, estos se mandan correctamente al controlador y se analizan, pero a la hora de llegar a la vista (que en este caso es un archivo con extensión jsp), se pierden.

He visto algunas preguntas similares en internet pero ninguna solución me ha servido. Voy siguiendo un tutorial de YouTube pero llevo días parado en este punto y no se como avanzar.

Persona.java

```
public class Persona {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String correo;
    private int pais;

    public Persona(int id, String nombre, String correo, int pais) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public void setPais(int pais) {
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    public Persona() {
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

}
```

PersonaValidar.Java

```
public class PersonaValidar implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return Persona.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
    }

    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        Persona persona = (Persona) o;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "nombre", "required.nombre", "El campo Nombre es obligatorio");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "correo", "required.correo", "El campo correo es obligatorio");
    }
}
```

FormController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/form")
public class FormController {

    private PersonaValidar personaValidar;

    public FormController() {
        this.personaValidar = new PersonaValidar();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView form() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("form", "persona", new Persona());
        return mav;
    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView form(
            @ModelAttribute("persona") Persona p,
            BindingResult result) {

        this.personaValidar.validate(p, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("form", "persona", new Persona());
            return mav;
        } else {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("exito");
            mav.addObject("nombre", p.getNombre());
            mav.addObject("pais", p.getPais());
            mav.addObject("correo", p.getCorreo());
            mav.addObject("id", p.getId());
            return mav;
        }
    }

    @ModelAttribute("paisLista")
    public Map<String, String> listadoPaises() {
        Map<String, String> pais = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        pais.put("1", "Chile");
        pais.put("2", "Madagascar");
        pais.put("3", "Túnez");
        pais.put("4", "España");
        pais.put("5", "Marruecos");
        pais.put("6", "Indonesia");
        return pais;
    }
}
```

form.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Título de página</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Ingrese sus datos</h1>
    </div>
    <form:form method="post" commandName="persona">

        <form:errors paths="*" element="div" cssClass="alert alert-danger" />

        <p>
            <form:label path="nombre">Nombre</form:label>
            <form:input path="nombre" cssClass="form-control"/>
            <form:errors path="nombre"/>
        </p>

        <p>
            <form:label path="correo">Correo</form:label>
            <form:input path="correo" cssClass="form-control"/>
            <form:errors path="correo"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <form:label path="pais">Pais</form:label>
            <form:select path="pais" cssClass="form-control">
                <form:options items="${paisLista}"/>
            </form:select>

        </p>
        <p>
            <form:label path="id">Id</form:label>
            <form:input path="id" cssClass="form-control"/>
        </p>
        <form:button>Enviar</form:button>
    </form:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

por tanto el error es el siguiente: Cuando el método Post de mi controlador analiza si el resultado tiene errores, da positivo, entra dentro del if pero al inicializar el jsp los errores no se muestran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que tu `JSP` tenga accceso a los errores encontrados en el backend, debes de incluir el objecto de la clase `BindingResult` en tu [respuesta del model](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#addObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), de esta manera:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView form(@ModelAttribute("persona") Persona persona, 
                         BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ...
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("form", "persona", persona);
        mav.addObject("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.persona", bindingResult);
        return mav;
    } else {
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```